# How to replace the character in one column at the position indicated by another column with the string in a different column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I am rather new to bioinformatics (this is my first post!) and I would appreciate some help on task that has me stuck.

I have a Tab-delimited data table with three columns:

```
AATTCTTGCA 4 [A/T]
AATTCCTTCG 7 [C/T]
AATTCAACAA 2 [T/C]
```

I would like to replace the character in the first column at the position indicated by the second column with the string in the third column so that the output is:

```
AAT[A/T]CTTGCA
AATTCC[C/T]TCG
A[T/C]TTCAACAA
```

I am working through various tutorials now and will update my post when I have some (failed) commands with `sed`/`awk`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `awk` command should do the task:

```
awk -F"\t" '{printf "%s%s%s%s",substr($1,1,$2-1),$3,substr($1,$2+1),ORS}' input.txt
```

The option `-F` sets the field separator to `TAB`. The program will then print (using the `printf()` function) for every line

- the substring of field 1 from the beginning up to (but excluding) the character position indicated in field 2
- the string contained in field 3
- the remainder of field 1, starting one past the character position indicated in field 2
- the "output record separator", which defaults to new-line

thereby effectively replacing the indicated character with the content of field 3.

**Note** that in hindsight this amount of explicit formatting control is actually not necessary, and the program can be abbreviated to

```
awk -F"\t" '{print substr($1,1,$2-1) $3 substr($1,$2+1)}' input.txt
```

**Caveat**: The program assumes that the character position in field 2 is always reasonable, i.e. greater than 0 and less or equal to the total length of field 1. If the file can be corrupt, more error-checking is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'my ($a,$b,$c) = .split("\t"); substr-rw($a, $b-1, 1) = $c; put $a;'
```

Sample Input:

```
AATTCTTGCA  4   [A/T]
AATTCCTTCG  7   [C/T]
AATTCAACAA  2   [T/C]
```

Sample Output:

```
AAT[A/T]CTTGCA
AATTCC[C/T]TCG
A[T/C]TTCAACAA
```

Briefly, data is read-in linewise using the `-ne` command-line flags. Each line is `split` on tabs, and assigned to scalars `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`. The `substr-rw` "substring-rewrite" command is used to take `$a` nucleotide sequence and assign `$c` string into a position defined by `$b-1` of length 1 (i.e. replacing 1 nucleotide). The revised `$a` nucleotide sequence is then out`put`.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/substr-rw
https://raku.org